# Keeping values in input fields when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage

I've been trying forever to keep the values the user entered into the added input fields when the web page is refreshed but with no success. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this so far I got the input fields to remain when the web page is reloaded. If it helps I'm using JQuery and PHP. My JQuery code is located below.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 10;
    var x = 1;

    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined'){
        $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            if(x < max_fields){
                x++;

                $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').append('<input type="text" name="first_name[]" /><input type="text" name="last_name[]" /><select name="title[]" class="title"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>');

                sessionStorage.setItem('Data',$(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').html());
            }
        });

        if(sessionStorage.getItem('Data')){
            $('.worker').closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').html(sessionStorage.getItem('Data')); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a mechanism to:

1. Devise a way to save data to session storage for all inputs
2. Trigger saving data to session storage (like a button or input change)
3. Iterate through all session storage on reload and find the ones you are interested in
4. Populate the fields with that data

Here's a sample for two text inputs:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined'){
    populateInputs();
  }

  function populateInputs(){
      for(var i=0; i<sessionStorage.length; i++) {
        var temp = sessionStorage.key(i);
        if(temp.startsWith('inputData')) {
            console.log('Setting ' + temp.split('-')[1] +
          ' to ' + sessionStorage.getItem(temp));
            $('#'+temp.split('-')[1]).val(sessionStorage.getItem(temp));
        }
      }
  }

  $('.saveInput').on('input', function(){
      sessionStorage.setItem('inputData-'+this.id, this.value);
  });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<label>First Name :</label><input type="text" class="saveInput" id="firstname"></input> <br>
<label>Last Name  :</label><input type="text" class="saveInput" id="lastname"></input>
```

Running example at https://plnkr.co/edit/MrAUBAMALOmYRwxLqBs0?p=preview

Comment: what about the select fields?

Comment: You could modify the code to include other input fields as well

Answer (score 0):

You could keep every `input` and `select` (and others if needed) value in local storage, save on unload and reload on page load. See simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).unload(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
    $('input, select').each(function(i,o) {
        $(o).val(localStorage[$(o).attr('id')])
    });
}

function saveSettings() {
    $('input, select').each(function(i,o) {
        localStorage[$(o).attr('id')] = $(o).val();
    });
}
```

This example save inputs and selects as key-value pairs based on their id attribute. It is dynamic and easily expandable.

[See it running](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/z9k3rc10/)